# A property of the Radon transform

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, radon-transform

In the book "S. Helgason, The Radon Transform, Birkh¨auser, Boston, Mass., 1980" 
You can find that Lemma $2.3$ claims :

$\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}^+: \ $ The integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} R(f)(p,w)\ p^k \,dp $$ can be written as a $k^{th}$ degree homogenous polynomial in $w_1,w_2,..., w_n$, here $R(f)$ is the Radon transform of $f\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Without precising what are those $w_1,w_2,..., w_n$ .

So first question: What are those vectors? Does it mean there simply exist some $n$ vectors.

My second question is about the proof, followed in the book; $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} R(f)(p,w)\ p^k \,dp= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \ p^k \int_{\langle x.w\rangle=p}f(x)dm(x) \,dp= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\langle x.w\rangle^kdx$$

I understand this equality but I don't follow why this means that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\langle x.w\rangle^kdx= g(w)$$ is a polynomial, and how about homegenous? 
And where those $w_1,w_2,..., w_n$ come from ?

Comment: ok $ \langle x.w\rangle= x_1+x_2+... +x_n $ in an orthonormal basis $w_1,w_2,..., w_n$ but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Radon transform $R(f)$ defined here is a function of $w$ and $p$, where $w$ is some unit vector and $p$ is a scalar. For some fixed input $w$, the $w_1, \dots, w_n$ are just the components of this vector in the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

This inner product is then $\left<x,w \right> = x_1w_1 + \dots x_nw_n$ so that $f(x)\left<x,w \right>^k$ is the sum of a bunch of terms of the form $f(x) \phi(x_1,\dots,x_n) \psi(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both a single $k$th degree term in their respective variables. This integrates "cleanly" w.r.t. $x$ so that you're just left with a bunch of terms that are $k$th degree in the $w_j$'s.

Comment: while I see this must be the answer I can't seem to spot that $(x_1w_1+...+x_nw_n)^k$ can be easily factored to separate the $w_i$

Comment: sorry, I think I wasn't being clear enough. The entire expression can't be easily factored, rather it is a sum of terms that can be easily factored - e.g. one of them will be $f(x)x_1^n w_1^n$ and $\int f(x) x_1^n w_1^n \, dx = \left(\int f(x) x_1^n \, dx\right) w_1^n$. Another term is  $f(x)x_1^{n-1} x_2 w_1^{n-1} w_2$ etc. There are a total of $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n-1)!}$ (number of ways to choose $k$ terms among $n$ with replacement, order does not matter) such terms, but each one remains $k$th degree in the $w_i$'s after integrating w.r.t. $x$.